# Get text from inside element without its children

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm scraping a webpage with several `p` elements and I wanna get the text inside of them without including their children.

The page is structured like this:

```
<p class="default">
    <div>I don't want this text</div>
    I want this text
</p>
```

When I use
`parent.find_all("p", {"class": "default").get_text()` this is the result I get:

```
I don't want this text
I want this text
```

I'm using BeautifulSoup 4 with Python 3

Edit: When I use

```
parent.find_all("p", {"class": "public item-cost"}, text=True, recursive=False)
```

It returns an empty list

Comment: You have two open `<div>` tags. Is that what you really have?

Comment: Sorry, typo. Fixed.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.find_next_sibling()` with `text=True` parameter:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html_doc = """
<p class="default">
    <div>I don't want this text</div>
    I want this text
</p>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, "html.parser")

print(soup.select_one(".default > div").find_next_sibling(text=True))
```

Prints:

```
I want this text
```

---

Or using `.contents`:

```
print(soup.find("p", class_="default").contents[-1])
```

---

EDIT: To strip the string:

```
print(soup.find("p", class_="default").contents[-1].strip())
```

Comment: contents[-1] should be stripped

Answer (score 0):

You can use xpath, which is a bit complex but provides much powerful querying.

Something like this will work for you:

```py
soup.xpath('//p[contains(@class, "default")]//text()[normalize-space()]')
```